# ASP.Net Web API Client Side Access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am struck in an issue:
Below is my controller code:

[image: Controller Code]

and this is how I am trying to access this method on client side:

[image]

I am getting internal server error:
**500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: you can have only one `[FromBody]` attribute in an action.

Comment: What you are trying to send is an object (complex type) with two properties email and password, and what you are trying to read is two strings (simple type). This is not going to work.

Comment: Ok you right, what if I want I want simple type on both side.I mean on web api side and also in ajax call. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually achieve the same in a more simpler way, see the working example  -

```
public class Test
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use, I know I can do that via class. Moreover I want to achieve this via javascript.

Comment: in that case you might want to send a `GET` with those data appended as query string parameters

Comment: It is post request , with get I can achieve this

Comment: Not everything in the framework is implemented at your will. Sorry

Comment: I think it can be implemented , anyway thanks for your time.